# Compositions of $n$ with $r$ odd parts and $s$ even parts

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

The problem I have been trying to figure out is as follows:

Let $n-r=2k$. Show that the number $f(n,r,s)$ of compositions of $n$ with $r$ odd parts and $s$ even parts is given by $\binom{r+s}{r}\binom{r+k-1}{r+s-1}$. Give a generating function proof.

The following hint is given:

It is clear that $\displaystyle \sum_{n,r,s} f(n,r,s)x^ny^rz^s=\sum_{j\geq 0} \left( \frac{yx}{1-x^2}+\frac{zx^2}{1-x^2} \right)^j$.

I can't figure out why the hint is obvious! I have been trying to figure out how to work with the following recursion I came up with:

$f(n,r,s)=f(n-1,r-1,s)+f(n-1,r,s)$,

which comes from partitioning the set of compositions of $n$ by considering the cases when $1$ is the smallest part and when some number greater than or equal to $2$ is the smallest part. However, my calculations come out insane! Anyone have a better suggestion for how to approach this problem or could you at least give some insight about the hint?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let's start with an easier question: if $f(n)$ is the number of compositions of $n$ (with no restrictions), then why is the generating function of $f$ equal to
$$
\sum_{n\ge0} f(n)x^n = \sum_{j\ge0} \bigg( \frac x{1-x} \bigg)^j?
$$
(The right-hand side simplifies to $1 + \sum_{n\ge1} 2^{n-1}x^n$, but that's irrelevant right now.) It's because the $j$th term, which is
$$
\bigg( \frac x{1-x} \bigg)^j = \big( x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + \cdots \big)^j,
$$
equals the number of compositions of $n$ into exactly $j$ parts.

And now I see that Brian M. Scott's answer contains the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve not had time to think much about the problem itself, but I can explain the hint. Let

$$g_{n,r,s}(x)=\frac{yx}{1-x^2}+\frac{zx^2}{1-x^2}=\sum_{k\ge 0}yx^{2k+1}+\sum_{k\ge 0}zx^{2k+2}\;.$$

The $x^n$ term in $g_{n,r,s}(x)$ is $yx^n$ if $n$ is odd and $zx^n$ if $n$ is even. In other words, this generating functions counts one odd part when $n$ is odd and one even part when $n$ is even: the coefficient of $x^ny^rz^s$ is the number of compositions of $n$ into one part such that $r$ parts are odd and $s$ are even.

Suppose that we square it; the resulting $x^n$ term is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n\Big([2\mid k]z+[2\nmid k]y\Big)\Big([2\mid n-k]z+[2\nmid n-k]y\Big)x^n\;.$$

If $n$ is even, this is

$$\Large\sum_{{0\le k\le n}\atop{k\text{ even}}}z^2x^n+\sum_{{0\le k\le n}\atop{k\text{ odd}}}y^2x^n\;;$$

if $n$ is odd, it’s

$$\Large\sum_{{0\le k\le n}\atop{k\text{ even}}}zyx^n+\sum_{{0\le k\le n}\atop{k\text{ odd}}}yzx^n=(n+1)yzx^n\;.$$

In either case the coefficient of each $x^ny^rz^s$ is the number of compositions of $n$ into two parts so that $r$ parts are odd and $s$ are even. If $n=2m$, there are $m+1$ compositions of $n$ into two even parts and $m$ compositions of $n$ into two odd parts; if $n$ is odd, there are $n+1$ compositions of $n$ into two parts, and in every case one part is odd and the other even.

In general $\big(g_{n,r,s}(x)\big)^j$ gives you the number of compositions of $n$ into $j$ parts, the exponents on $y$ and $z$ giving the the numbers of odd and even parts, respectively. This is why

$$\sum_{n,r,s}f(n,r,s)x^ny^rz^s=\sum_{j\ge 0}\left(\frac{yx}{1-x^2}+\frac{zx^2}{1-x^2}\right)^j\;.$$

**Added:** I’ve thought through the problem now and solved it. Unfortunately, I don’t really see how to reduce it to hints. I will mark a point part of the way through where you might want to stop reading and try to complete the argument yourself.

Recalling that $j$ is the number of parts, we can let $s=j-r$ and write

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\frac{yx}{1-x^2}+\frac{zx^2}{1-x^2}\right)^j&=\frac1{(1-x^2)^j}\sum_{r=0}^j\binom{j}ry^rz^{j-r}x^{2j-r}\\
&=\frac1{(1-x^2)^j}\sum_{r=0}^j\binom{j}ry^rz^sx^{r+2s}\\
&=\frac1{(1-x^2)^j}\sum_{r+s=j}\binom{r+s}ry^rz^sx^{r+2s}\;,
\end{align*}$$

where it’s understood that $r$ and $s$ are non-negative. A standard generating function is

$$\frac1{(1-x^2)^j}=\sum_{m\ge 0}\binom{j+m-1}mx^{2m}=\sum_{m\ge 0}\binom{j+m-1}{j-1}x^{2m}\;.$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{j\ge 0}\left(\frac{yx}{1-x^2}+\frac{zx^2}{1-x^2}\right)^j&=\sum_{j\ge 0}\frac1{(1-x^2)^j}\sum_{r+s=j}\binom{r+s}ry^rz^sx^{r+2s}\\
&=\sum_{j\ge 0}\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{r+s=j}\binom{j+m-1}m\binom{r+s}ry^rz^sx^{r+2s+2m}\;.\tag{1}
\end{align*}$$

---

> **At this point you could try to finish on your own.**

---

Let $n=r+2s+2m$; then $2k=n-r=2(s+m)$, $k=s+m$,

$$j+m-1=r+s+(k-s)-1=r+k-1\;,$$

and

$$\binom{j+m-1}m=\binom{j+m-1}{j-1}=\binom{r+k-1}{r+s-1}\;.$$

It’s not hard to check that with this renaming of quantities we can rewrite $(1)$ as

$$\sum_{r,s,n\ge 0}\binom{r+k-1}{r+s-1}\binom{r+s}ry^rz^sx^n\;;$$

you just have to verify $\sum_{j\ge 0}\sum_{m\ge 0}\sum_{r+s=j}\ldots$ and $\sum_{r,s,n\ge 0}\ldots$ run over the same combinations of exponents on $x,y$, and $z$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I see that the right side of the last equality above can be written as 1/(1-(what's in parentheses)). Is that useful for figuring out what the coefficient of $y^rz^s$ is? I don't see how to use that, but perhaps it is helpful.

Comment: @Sarah: It took a while to finish solving the problem and decide how to write it up, but here it is.

Comment: Thank you very much! I appreciate you going out of your way to help me understand the problem. The solution is very clear.

Comment: @Sarah: You're very welcome.